# Problems from Tomcat using different JDK as recommended by vendor

Tags: java, tomcat, confluence

We have Confluence running on Tomcat on a Linux server. The vendor clearly stated that it should only use JDK7 and not a new one. Given a mistake in the past, the JDK has been upgraded from JDK7 to JDK8. This was cought after some months of operation.

My question is: what implications can there be if you run using a different JDK?

Answer (score 0):

Java versions are normally backward compatible: Oracle takes great care to make sure that any Java program that works on an older Java version will also work on a newer Java version. It should normally work without the need to make changes to the program.

Despite the great care that Oracle takes, it's possible that there are some small incompatibilities. Each new version of the JDK comes with documentation that explains these possible incompatibilities with older versions. For JDK8, see: [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html).

However, it's still possible to write Java programs that won't work correctly on future Java versions, for example when you directly use classes that are supposed to be internal to the JDK (see: [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs 
That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)).

With regard to Confluence, it's probably the case that the vendor didn't formally test the version of Confluence that you are using with Java 8, so they don't want to formally guarantee that it works and give you support for it, although it might in practice not be a problem at all.